# Dynamically created TextBoxes in a Table lost Text value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a Table dynamically generated and inside of 2 columns there are TextBoxes. During the postback the Textboxes are always empty even if I fill them.
The table is builted in this way:

```
  protected void ddlScalaTaglie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtRighe = oTab.getScaleTaglieRighe(ddlScalaTaglie.SelectedValue);

        //dt is datatable object which holds DB results.
        Table tbl = new Table();
        tbl.CssClass = "table table-striped  table-bordered table-responsive";

        TableRow tr;
        TableCell tcEU, tcUS, tcUK, tcQty, tcEAN;
        Label lbEU, lbUS, lbUK, lbQty, lbEAN;
        TextBox tbEU, tbUS, tbUK, tbQty, tbEAN, tbToFocus = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtRighe.Rows)
        {
            tr = new TableRow();

            //ean
            tcEAN = new TableCell();
            tbEAN = new TextBox();
            tbEAN.ID = "txtEAN" + dr[0].ToString();
            tbEAN.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
            tbEAN.Columns = 15;
            tcEAN.Controls.Add(tbEAN); 
            tr.Controls.Add(tcEAN);

            //Qty
            tcQty = new TableCell();
            tbQty = new TextBox(); 
            tbQty.ID = "txtQty" + dr[0].ToString(); 
            tbQty.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Number; 
            tcQty.Controls.Add(tbQty);
            tr.Controls.Add(tcQty);            

            tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
        }

        Session["tbl"] = tbl;

        divTaglieRighe.Controls.Add(tbl);
    }
```

When I click the button SAVE, I have to loop throug my table and save all the TextBox.Text...

this is what I wrote:

```
 ArrayList arrScarpaFigli = new ArrayList();
 Table tbl = (Table)Session["tbl"];
 foreach (TableRow row in tbl.Rows)
 {
     foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
     {
        foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
        {
           //CONTROL IS TEXBOXT: EXTRACT VALUES//
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctrl;
                arrScarpaFigli.Add(txt.Text);
             }
         }
      }
  }
```

The problem is that, also if I fill the textboxes, in my Text there is always an empty string.
The only moment when I fill the table is on the selectionChange of a Dropdown.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090996/how-to-retrieve-data-from-tablecell-asp-net) post can solve your problem.

Comment: I set the ID dynamically

Comment: You have to retain the ViewState of the dynamically created controls on PostBack. Check out [this article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack.aspx) for further information.

Comment: @M.E. I take a look at the solution you posted but it's not the method that I need. I have a Table dynamically generated and inside of 2 columns there are TextBoxes

Comment: @Martina The problem here is that you are using dynamic controls without having the background knowledge necessary to make it work. Like many others have written, you must recreate the controls in the next post back to get it to work. Fortunately there are ready made Asp.Net controls that you can use instead: `GridView`, `ListView`, `Repeater` etc. Use these with databinding and you don't have to use dynamically created controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recreate dynamic controls on every page load to make sure their values are retained after a PostBack. So you need to create a new Method that handles the creation of the Table every time the page is loaded.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //always create the controls on every page load if there is a value selected in ddlScalaTaglie
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlScalaTaglie.SelectedValue))
    {
        createTable(ddlScalaTaglie.SelectedValue);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to find the Table inside the placeholder
    Table tbl = Page.FindControl("divTaglieRighe").FindControl("Table1") as Table;

    //loop all rows and cells in the Table
    foreach (TableRow row in tbl.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
            {
                //the control is a textbox
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    //cast the control back to a textbox
                    TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;

                    //does the checkbox have a value, if so append the label
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                    {
                        Label1.Text += tb.Text + "<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

protected void ddlScalaTaglie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //no need to create the Table dynamically, that will be handled in Page_Load
    //this method is just a dummy to trigger a PostBack

    //you could remove this method and the OnSelectedIndexChanged from the DropDown
    //and just keep the AutoPostBack="true", that will also work
}

private void createTable(string value)
{
    DataTable dtRighe = Common.LoadFromDB();

    //create a new table WITH id, that is needed for findcontrol
    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.ID = "Table1";

    //loop all rows in the datatable
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtRighe.Rows)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();

        //ean
        TableCell tcEAN = new TableCell();
        TextBox tbEAN = new TextBox();
        tbEAN.ID = "txtEAN" + dr[0].ToString();
        tbEAN.Width = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
        tbEAN.Columns = 15;
        tcEAN.Controls.Add(tbEAN);
        tr.Controls.Add(tcEAN);

        //Qty
        TableCell tcQty = new TableCell();
        TextBox tbQty = new TextBox();
        tbQty.ID = "txtQty" + dr[0].ToString();
        tbQty.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Number;
        tcQty.Controls.Add(tbQty);
        tr.Controls.Add(tcQty);

        tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
    }

    //add the table to the placeholder
    divTaglieRighe.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

The aspx to make the example complete

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlScalaTaglie" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlScalaTaglie_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="divTaglieRighe" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Comment: thanks, this evening I will try and I'll let you know!!

Answer (score 2):

Storing an instance of `Table` control in `Session` is a terrible idea and is just plain wrong. Controls belong to their parent page - they should be added to it as soon as they are created and they should die with their parent page.

The thing with dynamically created controls in ASP.NET is that you have to store an indicator of the fact that they were created (together with relevant information needed to create them again) and recreate them on all subsequent postbacks - no later than in `Page_Load`. Only then these controls will have the chance of getting their values from `Request` and you will have the chance of obtaining these values from controls.

In your code, the instance of `Table` stored in `Session` (together with all its rows, cells and textboxes) will never reflect any client-side data changes, nor will it belong to `Page`s that will be created to process subsequent postback requests.

*Update*

The important fact to understand here is that, after processing the postback caused by `ddlScalaTaglie` change and returning hew html to the client, the page instance is gone. On next request a new instance of your page is created - and it does not know anything about the fact that the previous instance had table added to its control tree. It is your code in `Page_Load` that must discover that the form must have this table, and create the table in exactly the same way it was created the first time - with rows, cells and textboxes with exactly the same `ID`s.

Then, after you add this newly created table to `divTaglieRighe.Controls`, the textboxes will be able to extract their client-side values from `Request.Form` collection.

Comment: but I can't recreate my controls on Page_Load... i I have to create the table after a dropdownlist item change because I read data from database. If on Page_Load I recreate my table I loose again the user inputs right?

Comment: no, the important thing to understand here is that after processing the postback caused by `ddlScalaTaglie` change and returning hew html to the client, the page instance is gone. On next request a new instance of your page is created - and it does not know anything about the fact that the previous instance had table added to it. It is your code in `Page_Load` that must discover that the form has to have this table, and create the table in exactly the same way it was created the first time - with rows, cells and textboxes with exactly the same `ID`s.

Comment: Then, after you add this newly created table to `divTaglieRighe.Controls`, the textboxes will be able to extract their client-side values from `Request.Form` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the textbox has a "name" for the post back to the controller.
If it does not it grabs a null for the parameter.

Check Request.Form for data returned to controller.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a Table called `tbl` and added two `TextBox`, then you store Table control in session `Session["tbl"]` and added to `divTaglieRighe` control. Finally you are trying to get TextBox data from your session `Session["tbl"]` table not the ViewState control that added in `divTaglieRighe` control. You have to get data from you Table `tbl` control that added in `divTaglieRighe` control.